# SQL compilation error: JSON file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array when copying from S3 to Snowflake

Tags: json, amazon-s3, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following JSON stored in S3:

```
{"data":"this is a test for firehose"}
```

I have created the table `test_firehose` with a varchar column data, and a file_format called `JSON` with type JSON and the rest in default values. I want to copy the content from s3 to snowflake, and I have tried with the following statement:

```
COPY INTO test_firehose
FROM 's3://s3_bucket/firehose/2020/12/30/09/tracking-1-2020-12-30-09-38-46'
FILE_FORMAT = 'JSON';
```

And I receive the error:

```
    SQL compilation error: JSON file format can produce one and only one column of type 
variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.
```

How could I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Snowflake supports following semi structure data type to store semi structure data:
Variant, Object and Array.
Try change table column data type to variant and try load the data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your data as JSON (rather than just as text) then you need to load it into a column with a datatype of VARIANT, not VARCHAR